# Как установить base url в axios + express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, ssr

Есть nodejs сервер на **express** с **ssr**, так же есть отдельный сервер с данными. Запросы за данными раньше отправлялись только на клиенте и все пути относительные (к серверу с данными) т.к. выполнялось на клиенте с нужным доменом. Когда начали отправлять запросы с сервера, получили проблему, что не туда запросы отправляются из-за относительного пути.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то настроить express так, что бы узказать ему опредлённый url, который подставлялся бы в относительные пути при отправке запросов за данными c сервера, через axios?
Или может есть какое нибудь другое решение?**